# List of String from List of object in java 7

Tags: java, java-7

I've a list of user object. And I want to get list of user name except using loop. 
Is there any collection or util function in java 7??

Comment: what is the problem with for loop

Comment: try to add code that you have done so far.

Comment: performance issue. My list contains huge user list.

Comment: @Rounak: there is no way to do that without a loop. Whatever library you find, it will always use a loop. What is "huge"?

Comment: @shreyanshjogi nothing wrong, just seems like OP uses python/js or some other language with syntactic sugar which allows you to express it in pretty one-liner. :)

Comment: @Rounak How many items are in your user list?

Comment: @JBNizet There *is* a way to do it without a loop, by creating a *view* into the underlying User list. Maybe Guava has something like that? Whether that would solve OP's performance issue highly depends on his access pattern of the name list.

Comment: 5,000 users is *not* a huge list.

Comment: @Rounak 5000 items in a List is a ridiculously small number.  There's no performance issues involved here, trust me.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Agreed. Guava indeed has such a view: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform%28java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29. But I doubt the user won't consume the name list. And he's doing premature optimization anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no util function. It's 3 lines of code to do it yourself.

Even if there was a util function, it wouldn't help with performance. It would be implemented as a for loop.

As for performance, have you actually profiled your application and seen that iterating the List is a performance hotspot?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is:

```
for (String pos: User) {
    System.out.println(pos.toString());
}
```

This uses an Iterator, but since 1.5 Java you can use this shorthand to not show the Iterator.